# How can I find the face of the items in the headeline in lsp-mode?

Tags: faces, terminal-emacs, help, lsp-mode

**Re-edited the answer for clarity**

Typically I would put my cursor over the text, and call `M-x describe-face`, but I can't do that with the headerline.

[image: screenshot of LSP headerline in no-window mode with a dark background]

In the above screenshot, I want to change the headerline to something contrasting.  If I could change the light grey to something darker, it would do the job.  So I tried to identify the base faces.  So far I found these 3:

1. `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-path-face`: underlined in red
2. `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-separator-face`: the `>` separator, underlined in yellow (but invisible because it disappears into the background)
3. `lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-symbols-face`: underlined in cyan

But I can't figure out the spaces in between.  If I change the `*-symbols-*` and `*-path-*` faces listed above by adding `:background "brightblack"`, and `*-separator-*` to just `:foreground "black"`, I can only change the underlined parts (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot of LSP headerline in no-window mode with a dark background custom attempt]

I also looked at the results of `list-faces-display` (without my customisation), there is no light grey background (see screenshot below).  So I think something other than these faces is giving the light grey background, if I could change that, I wouldn't need to change them individually or find the face for the intermediary spaces.

[image: list-faces-display]

**Follow-up to NickD's question:**

`header-line-format` is set to:

```lisp
((t
  (:eval
   (window-parameter nil 'lsp-headerline--string))))
```

When I try to get the value of `lsp-headerline--string` with `C-h v`, I get the message `[No match]`.

Comment: In that buffer, what does `C-h v header-line-format` say? It should contain some face information I think.

Comment: @NickD please see my edit

Comment: You say you don't see any that have the light-gray background you're looking for. But to me it seems that *all* of the path and symbols faces have that background. Keep in mind that the header line doesn't use the same background as your frame, so faces used there won't appear to be the same as they are elsewhere even when they're actually exactly the same (e.g., same gray in different surrounding context). If *your own* code is giving the faces that background, then it sounds like you're the culprit. ;-)

Comment: ... and what's the value of `lsp-headerline--string`? I guess that the above is meant to cause a refresh when the string is modified.

Comment: @Drew sorry, I think my initial question wasn't worded clearly.  I have re-edited everything for clarity.  I hope it is clearer now

Comment: @NickD `C-h v` cannot find a match for that variable, maybe it's something that's internal to `lsp-mode`?

Comment: Are you doing it from the relevant buffer? It's most probably buffer-local.

Comment: @NickD Yup, I'm doing it from the Python buffer I'm in.  That said, I think I found the culprit, it's `header-line`, but I'm not clear on why it's happening.  I'm posting an answer below with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Drew's hints, I found the relevant face by looking at the whole list from `list-faces-display` one by one.  It was coming from `header-line`, which inherits from `mode-line`.  But I still don't understand why this is happening, because none of the `lsp-headerline-*` faces actually inherit from `header-line`.  For example:

```
Hide [Lsp Headerline Breadcrumb Path Face]:[sample]
   [ State ]: STANDARD.
   Face used for breadcrumb paths on headerline.
   [X] Inherit:
       [INS] [DEL] Face: [link] (sample) font-lock-string-face
       [INS]
   Show All Attributes
```

Maybe header line is special in some way, and applies two faces.

Comment: It's possible that two or more faces are present at the same place, in which case their attributes are combined. And there can be both overlays and text properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x list-faces-display`. Use it on a frame that has the same background as the frame where you see the face you're looking for. Find the face that looks like what you see there. Then `M-x customize-face`.

If you find more than one face that looks the same, then check each one.  Use `M-x customize-face` to change a face's appearance so you can see which one is the one you're looking for.

What you see can also be the result of a *combination of faces* that are merged at that location. Look for a face that shows you the light gray background you're looking for.

(`M-x describe-face` also tells you about a face, but it doesn't let you change it, to see whether that's the face you're looking for.)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't tell me where the light grey background is coming from.  I edited my question to add another screenshot

Comment: As I said, use `M-x customize-face` to check an individual face's attributes in detail. What you see can also be a combination of faces that are merged. Look for a face that does show you the light gray background you're looking for. (I've updated the answer to mention face combination.)